# How does IntelliJ IDEA change text type remarks into formatting Java docs notes?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

For example, when I usually write a class notes, are directly write note text, rather than add the Java doc format content, such as < p > this. But after I finished writing, hope to be able to a key formatting, converted to Javadoc format, the great god, have shortcut? Or plug-ins?

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Could you please give an example of what you have written ("class notes") and how you would like IDEA to format it?

Comment: example : When I create a new class, I'll write some class comments on the top of the class, but these comments are  only text (not the standard javadoc comments), and I want a shortcut to convert to  javadoc comments.

Comment: Please give a concrete example! Javadoc is basically just HTML, so what you said so far sound to me like: I enter some plain text. I want some magic way to add HTML tags. What tags exactly? Where exactly?

Comment: fixed product name to match JetBrains naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Just start your comment with `/**` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

As alternative you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the class name and select **Add Javadoc**